# why var/cache folder is not deleting

Tags: cache

we are using magento 1.9.0 version.

we  are trying to delete cache fodler, but it's not working.....

we tried in both ssh and in manual way. but still cache folder is not deleting.

if it delete also, within a minute cache folder will recreate with all following folders.

"mage-0, mage-1, mage-2............ mage-9 , mage-a, mage-b, mage-c....etc

please help me to find solution

Comment: is this on a live environment?

Comment: yes, in live..... we moved from one site to another.....

Comment: Put on hold as "too broad" ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have indicated this is a live environment which means visitors call the pages on the installation.

Whenever you remove a cache folder Magento will create a new version as soon as a user visits a certain page on the website. So this is actually desired behaviour

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature! ;)

Comment: hi sander & Anna is there any problem from this? because usually if we do some changes in coding, to display in frontend we have to remove cache.... so i asked this question......

Comment: Nope, you can flush cache and it'll apply your changes but will rebuild the cache right away

Comment: if i "flush magento cache" is that enough?

Comment: if cache i keep on storing means, will there be any problem?

Comment: flushing is enough. no problems